# Hard drive failure

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive-recovery

I first encountered the error 0x80071A91 while installing all windows features. But System couldn't install windows feature  "Windows subsystem under Linux". Hence I reset my HP Notebook 1000 PC (Windows 10, 64 bits, version 22H2)with "keep my personal files" option. But I couldn't get rid of that error 0x80071A91. Hence I again reset my PC with " All personal files remove" but that made my adminstrator account deletion and   my computer keep restarting again and again.

When I checked hard drive under UEFI settings, It showed short and long dst check tests failed.  Now how can I recover my Hard drive?  Shall I require to replace my hard drive? How can I repair it from the command prompt under " Windows Recovery Environment"? I tried  all attempts to restart and clean reinstallation windows 10 on the hard drive. It keeps restarting again and again. Do I require to call hp service engineer?

Answer (score 2):

Your disk has failed and need to be replaced.

Symptoms : Installing Windows fails, Windows Update fails,
disk tests fail.
Only one conclusion is possible : The disk has died,
replace as soon as possible.

Comment: But I think by downloading the media creation tool(Windows10) on USB flash drive(pen drive),  i can boot from my pen drive. Is that correct? How to repair hard drive from X drive ? (X: Windows\System32)

Comment: A dead drive cannot be "repaired". This is a hardware problem, and disk are too complicated electronically to be repaired, even by a professional. You need to understand that this disk cannot be saved.

Comment: I factory reset my PC. Now my hard drive is fine. But I require to reinstall windows 8.1 single language and then I require to reinstall windows 10 single language.  At present, I have windows 8 single language on my PC(factory reset). :-)

Comment: If your disk has failed UEFI tests, you will have problems in the future. You use this disk at your own risk.